# Zero Currency (Euro) defined field tested for 0 not recognised as 0

Tags: calculation

I have a table of invoices with Invoice Amount HT, TVA, and Invoice Amount TTC all defined as Currency, Euro, decimal place auto.  I assumed that being defined as Currency, Euro, there could only be 2dp.  However, although all these amounts are displayed in the table as 2dp, if I click on the field it shows in some cases as more than 2dp.  So, for example, looking at the table datasheet view, I have an invoice with Amount HT of €550.32, TVA of €110.06 and Amount TTC of €660.38 which all looks fine.  But if I select these fields I notice that the TVA field shows as 110.064 and the Amount TTC shows as 660.384.  When a payment is received it is added to the Amount Paid field (also defined as Currency Euro), and the Balance field (also defined as Currency Euro) is calculated as Amount TTC - Amount Paid.  If the Balance is 0, I set the Completed Date to the date of the payment.  The problem is that with this case it didn't recognise the Balance as 0 because it treated it as 0.004.  This causes the case to be omitted from my Completed Sales Report.  When TVA is to be added, it is calculated as  Amount HT*0.2 (the TVA Rate).  It is this calculation that is creating the problem.

Is there a way of avoiding this please?

Comment: It would help a lot if you would show us code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The "code" is simply  "Amount HT*0.2".  However, I came across this:
"If we take the currency data type as an example this is expressed to a precision of four decimal places and usually formatted to two decimal places, e.g. £25.17.  Computations on the value do so on the underlying value with a precision of four decimal places however.  This is to reduce cumulative rounding errors sufficiently for everyday currency calculations."
I conclude from this that I need to Round to 2dp in my calculation